# How to get verbose output for spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am writing a spring boot application utilizing spring-jpa (hibernate) and I'm trying to determine a good shema management process.

Regarding the ddl-auto property, I cannot use "create" or "update" in production and I must manage the schema manually. So I set the ddl-auto to "validate".

However, I am not getting verbose output. The server fails to start but I am not getting any logs explaining what is wrong with the schema. When the schema matches, the server starts normally. Here's what my logs say when the schema does not match:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.3.RELEASE)

2018-09-07 11:35:25.388  INFO 13928 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-09-07 11:35:25.390  INFO 13928 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.31
2018-09-07 11:35:25.392  INFO 13928 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [REDACTED]
2018-09-07 11:35:25.465  INFO 13928 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-09-07 11:35:25.855  INFO 13928 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-09-07 11:35:25.888  INFO 13928 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-09-07 11:35:25.937  INFO 13928 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-09-07 11:35:25.986  INFO 13928 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
2018-09-07 11:35:25.987  INFO 13928 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-09-07 11:35:26.023  INFO 13928 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-09-07 11:35:26.120  INFO 13928 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2018-09-07 11:35:26.698  INFO 13928 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-09-07 11:35:26.701  WARN 13928 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-09-07 11:35:26.702  WARN 13928 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 connection adder] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
 java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-09-07 11:35:26.705  INFO 13928 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-09-07 11:35:26.708  INFO 13928 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So my question is - how do I get more verbose logging that tells me the exact validation errors?

Comment: Based on the warning from HikariPool it doesn't look like a hibernate validation error

Comment: Right, you should be seeing the validation errors. There is another issue here. What's you're configuration?

Comment: Which configuration are you looking for? I don't have any custom logging config, however I have noticed that I never get good logging when the server fails to start.